# Special area route (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a unusual problem with ASP.NET MVC3 Routing. I created a area named "Account" and inside that a controller "Main" with action "Login". Now I wanted to create a route, that would look something like this: "/Login" (that means no "/Account/Main/Login"), but I keep failing to do that (I have used the `AccountAreaRegistration` to register routes, but `@Html.ActionLink` always skips them and chooses the default area route (`"/Account/{controller}/{action}"`, thus the URL is different from what I want). How can I proceed and solve this issue?

Comment: Could you show your code for setting up the routes? The routes are parsed in an "from-top-to-bottom" order, i.e. in the same order you write them in your code, so if you have the default route *above* the special one, your special route is never going to be matched.

Comment: Also, [Phil Haack's routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) might be helpful. It's rather old, though, so I'm not sure if he's updated it to support areas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue, it was actually quite stupid. The order of the routes was OK, but the problem was caused by the fact I did use area = "Account" default value in the list of MapRoute's default values. After I deleted it, everything works like a charm.